# Spring authorization-server with custom login flow

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I'm trying out spring authorization-server for my project and need to customize the login flow.

Instead of username/password login, a ticket should be created in the backend connected to a QR-code that's displayed in the frontend.
The user then scans the code with our app that will authenticate the user using MTLS and claim the ticket.
While the user authenticates themselves through the app the browser will poll the status of the ticket and once the ticket is claimed, the login step is completed and should proceed to the consent page.

My issue is that I don't really understand how to customize the backend logic of the login step and I can't seem to find much information about it.
All I've found regarding custom login is replacing the frontend using:

```
http.formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .build();
```

I've played around with the messages samples which implements a custom consent flow, but nothing regarding login.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you're describing sounds very similar to the [OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Grant](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8628). See [#44](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/44).

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Yeah, it looks very similar!
Do you know anything about when it will be supported?

Comment: For sure not until after 1.0 is released (in November 2022).